# NativeScript: how to avoid editing build.gradle in platforms/android

Tags: nativescript

In order to get Firebase messaging running I had to do some editing in the build.gradle file in platforms/android. If I do a `tns platform remove/add` then my modifications are gone. Is it somehow possible to put something in app/App_Resources/android to prevent from my changes to disappear. A consideration here is that app/** is in Git whereas platform/** is not.

Answer (score 9):

Yes. Use the `app.gradle` file located in *App_Resources/Android*.

Since this file is specific to your app it won't be removed when it's necessary to remove/add the platform to fix android build issues. I don't recall the exact NS version this was added but I think it was **1.7**. Hope that helps.